# trying to create a class objext iside an other class

Tags: java, class, object

I am trying to create an object of a class point into another class `InterestPoint`, with some words i want to be able to use Points values inside my `INterestPoint` class but without the use of heredity

```
public class InterestPoint {

    private Point p1;
    private String aeria;

    public InterestPoint() {
        this.p1 = new Point();
        //p1.dysplay1();
    }

}
```

---

**Edit**

no you misunderstand when i call my method to print my point through the class functions it print me an error that say :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at Point.dysplay1(Point.java:29)
    at InterestPoint.setall1(InterestPoint.java:22)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
Java Result: 1
```

thats why i posted this question :D

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Where are you stuck? How are you stuck? You could use composition as you're doing and provide a getter method for p1. Note that I tried to fix your code formatting. In the future you're going to want to do this yourself for any code that you post here.

Answer (score 0):

Re:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
>     at Point.dysplay1(Point.java:29)
>     at InterestPoint.setall1(InterestPoint.java:22)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:16)
> Java Result: 1
> ```

Shoot, you're not showing your whole InterestPoint class to us, especially the method that you have that must look something like:

```
public void setAll1() {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet");
}
```

The solution is to get rid of that throws call and put in code that makes sense.

```
public void setAll1() {
   // get rid of this throw exception call
   // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet");

   // add some sensible code here
}
```